# Coulomb's Law in a medium

Tags: electrostatics, dielectric

We have coulomb's law in vaccum as $$F=\frac{q_1q_2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2}$$

However, for medium, I read in my book that :

$$F_1=\frac{q_1q_2}{4\pi \epsilon r^2}$$
, where $\epsilon=\epsilon_0k$ and $F_1$ is the force applied by both medium and charge and it is the *net* force on the charge. And:

$$F_2=\frac{q_1q_2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)$$

or

$$F_1=F-F_2$$

Where $F_2$ is the force applied by medium *only*. I doubt why the medium is applying force here on the charge. And what is the role/significance of $k$ dielectric constant here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dielectric material aligns with the electric field to reduce the effective electric field.  The simplest large scale example is a capacitor with one positive plate and one negative plate.  The dielectric material between the plates aligns so that a negative surface is adjacent to the positive plate and a positive surface is adjacent to the negative plate.  This produces an electric field that opposes the original electric field from only the plates.  On a small scale, the polarized molecules of the dielectric material align such that the field between adjacent molecules is opposite the direction of the electric field that rotates these molecules.  These aligned molecules do exert force on the original charges.  The stronger the charges and original electric field between the charges, the more aligned the dipole molecules of the dielectric will be.